# React Router: How to fix BrowserRouter showing the blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to JS react and I'm currently working on the routing portion of my project.
I'm trying to utilize the *BrowserRouter* function imported from the *react-router-dom* package. But upon issuing *npm start* all I get is a blank white screen as seen in image (2). If I directly call my ***LandingPage.js** with the code I commented out on image (1) it outputs the screen shown in image (3) which is what I'm trying to output with the **BrowserRouter** method. Am I missing anything?

1.)
[image]

2.)

[image]

3.)
[image]

Comment: what version are you using of react-router-dom?

Comment: Please edit the question to have the code instead of images. It would be so much easier to work it around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `react-router-dom` V6, then you have to use Routes and Route both at a time to make it work.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
```

And update the App function.

```
function App() {
  return (
     
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Header />
       <main className="py-1">
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage/>} />
        </Routes>
      
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The [Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview) has a pretty good example to understand that

> Note: If you are using `react-router-dom` v5 or below then Import and
> use `Switch` instead of `Routes` for this purpose,  `Switch` is been
> depreciated in v6.

Comment: Some thing went wrong when you error syntax
Error white screen: <Route path="/" element={LandingPage} />   (Missing <LandingPage />)